# SDWebImage error

Tags: swift, image, sdwebimage

I'm trying to use SDWebImage :

```
 profileImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "\(photoUrl)&wstoken=\(wstoken)"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "ic_male"))
```

but I am getting an error that says:

```
 TCallViewController.swift:85:13: Value of type 'UIImageView' has no member 'sd_setImage'
```

I have searched many solutions but none of them helped me! how can I solve this problem

Comment: have you import SDWebImage in your controller ?

Comment: i have tried to import in my bridging-header file but that doesn't work !! it can't find that file in Pods however when I use it in objective c classes that works but in swift no

Comment: No have you import SDWebimage in your ViewController ?

Comment: are you using cocoapods or directly sdwebimage in your project?

Comment: ok i will try it and I hope that it works

Comment: I'm using cocoapods !

Comment: @import SDWebImage; import in bridging-header  it will work.

Comment: thanks that's work perfectly